# Chances of receiving 2nd H1-B visa after quitting 1st H1-B job

Tags: h1b-visas

In 2013 I applied for an H1-B work visa for the U.S. The visa was approved and I moved to the U.S. After four months of working there I quit my job, though, and returned to Europe.
I am now, several months later, thinking about applying for another H1-B visa with another company. The job description of the new job is almost identical to the old one

I wanted to know whether the fact that I quit my job on the first H1-B visa diminishes my chances of being approved for another H1-B visa

Comment: I am trying to get a concrete answer to this, but I would think that your prior approval combined with your leaving (properly) the country after quitting the job for which you received it would actually increase your chances of getting a new one.

Comment: Hi. I'm afraid this site is for recreational travel. You might like to look at our Expatriates' site to see if this question can be answered. http://expatriates.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DJClayworth I see from [the help center](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) that questions about work visas are indeed off-topic, but do you have a reference to support that questions here are restricted to "recreational" travel?  The [only reference I found expressly welcomes questions about business travel](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/a/996).

Comment: @alx9r Yes, my mistake. I meant short term travel.